# What is the best practice to show a progress in angulardart?

Tags: dart, progress-bar, future, progress, angular-dart

I tried to show a progress in angulardart, and thought that a Future would be good for this. But then i realized that a Future must be recursive to show a progress, since the Future returns immediately and the lengthy operation is executed afterwards.

If i create a Future that calls itself until the end condition is met it works with the progressbar. But i think this could not be a very good practice sind these calls will raise the memory on the stack with every recursion. Just consider a loop going through 1 billion datasets that could run a few hours and every loop calls a new Future within the current Future.

Is there a better way to create a loop that needs a certain amount of time to do work on every element (including calling a website that must be done asynchronous and evaluating the return value)? During the loop the user should see a progress that shows him "x/1000000 done".

I think it must be done with a Future since the UI needs to reload after initiating the loop, but a recursive Future seems like a bad idea to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile i recognized that a Future-method returns immediately without executing anything in the method-body. So the solution is pretty easy:

Just declare the rpc with a Future, do whatever you need to do in the method and when calling it, use then(...) to do what you need to do after collecting the data.

```
int progress = 0;
int progressMax = 100;
bool progressCanceled = false;

Future rpc(var data)
async{
  for(progress=0; progress<progressMax, progress++)
  {
    // do whatever you need to do with data
    if(progressCanceled)
      return;
  }
}

rpc(data).then(
{
  if(progressCanceled)
    return;
  // do whatever is needed after having received that data
});
```

rpc is executed and the calling process can continue while rpc does what rpc has to do. The main program can handle button clicks to set progressCanceled to true and the rpc-method will ask for the state and stop processing if it is set.

Answer (score 2):

You need the future to return back to you right away on the web because it is a single threaded platform. If an async action didn't return until it was complete then you would hang the browser and it wouldn't be a great experience to the user.

Instead you have a couple of options:

Dart has the ability to make the future look like it is synchronous with the await keyword. So you can do something like:

```
void performAction() async {
  showProgress = true;
  await expensiveRpc();
  showProgress = false;
}
```

This would require the progress to be intermediate, as you aren't actually updating the progress bar as it goes along. That said if you don't really get progress events from your RPC this is probably the better solution.

Now if your RPC or action gives you some kind of feedback as it goes you can do something a bit nicer with a stream.

```
void performAction() {
  showProgress = true;
  expensiveRpc().listen((progress) {
    if (progress.done) {
      showProgress = false;
    } else {
      percentComplete = progress.value;
    });
}
```

Really it depends more on the RPC or service you are interacting with on how you can update the progress nicely more than the progress itself.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I have to take a closer look at streams, but this could work for my purpose. thank you for pointing that out :)